# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, apache

I can't use any php extension. PHP works without unccommented extensions.
Text from error.log:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'd:/work/www/php/ext/{any_extension}.dll'

I have Windows 10 x64, PHP7 x64, Apache 2.4 x64;

Extensions line in php.ini:

> extension_dir = "d:/work/www/php/ext/"

Path is correct

I added this in the Windows PATH:

> d:/work/www/php
>   d:/work/www/php/ext
>   d:/work/www/apache
>   d:/work/www/apache/bin

Text from phpinfo:

> extension_dir - d:/work/www/php/ext

Syntax like

> extension=D:/work/www/php/ext/{any_extension}.dll

in php.ini doesn't change anything.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I think you must replace `/` with \
 in your path. `extension_dir = "d:\work\www\php\ext\"`

Comment: Forward slashes are fine. You have verified that the directory exists and the extensions you're trying to load are actually there?

Comment: smoqadam, nope, you can write / or \, it doesn't change anything. And yes, I tried.

Comment: Markus AO, of course, it all exists.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that:

- extensions in your `php.ini` are noted as `extension=curl`, `extension=ldap`, etc. 
  PHP 7+ config uses this format instead of `extension=php_curl.dll` in previous versions (which is still supported for legacy reasons, but is deprecated).
- config line `extension_dir = "C:/path_to_your_php/"` contains absolute path to your php extensions dir.
- proper Visual C++ Redist's are installed in your system. E.g. **PHP 7 x64** and **Apache 2.4 x64** both require VCRedist 2017 (x64: https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vc_redist.x64.exe, x86: https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vc_redist.x86.exe)
- add config lines below to your `<apache_dir>/conf/httpd.conf` file:

```
Loadfile "path_to_php_dir/libsasl.dll"
LoadFile "path_to_php_dir/libpq.dll"
LoadFile "path_to_php_dir/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "path_to_php_dir/libssh2.dll"
LoadFile "path_to_php_dir/nghttp2.dll"
LoadFile "path_to_php_dir/libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll"
LoadFile "path_to_php_dir/libssl-1_1-x64.dll"
```

This makes Apache to preload these files so your extensions wouldn't fail on load.
You can add any other DLL from your `/php` directory if some extensions need it.

- other extensions DLLs and/or PHP DLLs dependencies are not missed. You can use free "Dependency Walker" tool (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to inspect each of DLL files loading for missed dependencies (`php_dir/php*.dll`, `php_dir/ext/*.dll`, ...).

Answer (score 0):

In my Apache configuration "*C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf*"

`PHPIniDir "C:\Apache24\php-7.4.29"` → fail 
`PHPIniDir "C:\Apache24\php-7.4.29\"` → ok - notice the backslash at the end !

---

```bash
# extract of httpd.conf
LoadModule php7_module "C:\Apache24\php-7.4.29\php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:\Apache24\php-7.4.29\"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php 

# extract of php.ini
extension_dir = "C:\Apache24\php-7.4.29\ext\"

...
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
...
```

Comment: Do not add the same answer, vote to close instead